# RewriteRule won´t work with new domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I´ve made some RewriteRules in my .htaccess and they all work if I call my Website from the Domain/URL of my server.

Now I wanted to point an external Domain to my subfolder on my server where my Website is located, but all RewriteRules aren´t working anymore. When I call the php-files everything is alright, but when I call my "beautiful" links, I wanted to create, then only error 404 is shown.

This is currently my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On

#redirect www request to the base domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] 

#ignore existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Check if query string exists
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

# Check that the request is not for an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule    ^spielplan$    spielplan.php    [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^rangliste$    rangliste.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^alletipps$    allbets.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^benutzerseite$    userpage.php    [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^einstellungen$    usersettings.php    [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^spiel/([0-9]+)/?$    spiel.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^user/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    user.php?name=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    $1.php    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Because I tried to map my domain to a subfolder, this subfolder needs to work like an DocumentRoot and not like a subfolder.

So I needed to add:

```
RewriteBase /
```

in my .htaccess